# Properties of $x$ that make $x^2 \equiv x+1 \mod p$, where $p$ is prime

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Excuse me for putting in a pinch of computer science.

For a pre-calculated prime $p$, I need to find all natural $x$ that make $x^2 = x+1 \mod p$. The problem is that trying thoroughly every $x < p$ is too inefficient. The only optimization I could think of is start at $x = \sqrt{p}$.

What other optimizations can be made to farther increase the algorithm efficiency?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499644/show-that-the-odd-prime-divisors-of-the-integer-n2n1-which-are-different-fr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $4 x^2 - 4 x - 4 \equiv 0 \pmod p,$ so $4 x^2 - 4 x  +1 \equiv 5 \pmod p,$ that is $$  (2x-1)^2 \equiv 5 \pmod p. $$ So, first you need $(5|p) = 1,$ or $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5.$

Next you need the square roots $\pm t$ of $5 \pmod p.$ The algorithms for doing this are called [Tonelli-Shanks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) and [Cipolla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm).

Finally, you solve $2x-1 \equiv t \pmod p$ and $2x-1 \equiv -t \pmod p.$

Comment: Thanks alot! If you've got some free time I'd recommand you to solve [problem 437](http://projecteuler.net/problem=437) (which is what I needed the assistance for), it was very enjoyable for me. ;) Also, I hope you don't mind, I had to use some of your text in my post at the problem's forum.

Answer (score 1):

There will be solutions if and only if $p$ is within 1 of a multiple of 5. In such a case, there will be a solution to $u^2\equiv5\pmod p$ (in fact, exactly 2 solutions, modulo $p$), and you can take $x=(1\pm u)/2$.

So what you have to look up is algorithms for solving $u^2\equiv a\pmod p$. Start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).